# How does the Microsoft Account work w/o authentication on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-account

I would like to gain some understanding of the *Microsoft Account* authentication for Windows 8.1.  Indeed, Windows 8.1 distinguish the *local* accounts (like it was in all previous versions since Windows NT) from the *Microsoft* accounts (which delegate the authentication *somehow* to the cloud).

In particular:

- Does the authentication works offline?
- If I change the password online, does it change the local password as well?
- If yes, when does the sync local/cloud happens? Anytime? Only at login time?
- In a corporate context, can I use [Live ID for domains](http://www.domains.live.com/) to reset the local password of a user?

Answer (score 0):

Windows authentication works online only since vista, maybe earlier. If I'm not mistaken, with some Microsoft software, you can authenticate the software offline if you call them.

Change the password to what exactly,

Your Account Password -> Can be done offline

Your LIVE ID -> Has to be done online

I don't understand your last question.

Basically anything with LIVE ID needs to be done online.